# In checkout when i get to the payment information i get this error. Attention [XML2Array] Error parsing the XML string

Tags: checkout, xml, php-7

[image]

This would be the last step in the checkout process. I hit checkout and it would take me to a success page. Right when i hit the button it throws this error.

I did a search on the server for what would display that error message and this is what i found. two modules.

```
./app/code/ParadoxLabs/TokenBase/Model/Gateway/Xml.php:154:                    __('[XML2Array] Error parsing the XML string.')
./app/code/IWD/AddressValidation/Model/XML/XML2Array.php:56:                throw new LocalizedException(__('[XML2Array] Error parsing the XML string.'));
```

Has anyone encountered this problem with paradox labs or the IWD module? Is it possible that there could just be some rogue spaces in the xml files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have configured the payment extension(ParadoxLabs/TokenBase) correctly with sandbox/live credentials. This resolves the issue.

Thanks!
Nithin Ninan